# output data to cell

Tags: google-apps-script

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').appendRow([new Date(), VARname])
```

I know the above code there will output the varable to a cell, but how would you output it to a specific cell, like B50 or A4, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
.appendRow
```

in your code above use

```
.getRange(row#, column#).setValue(variable);
```

In your case B50 would be

```
.getRange(50,2).setValue(VARname);
```

Comment: or also in A1 notation .getRange('B50').setValue(VARname)

Comment: Yes, but what fun is that? :)

Comment: nothing fun, just an info for some people that wouldn't have read the doc ;-)

Comment: If I wanted to keep the date being output also, how would it look? Example: Date and time in A1 & the VARoutput in B1. (Trying to figure it out)

Comment: .getRange('A1').setValue(date.Now());  //something like this.

Comment: `.getRange('A1:B1').setValues([[new Date(),VARoutput]]);`

Comment: Mogsdad: If you set it to 'A1:B1' , it will over-right the data each time it's pulled, I wanted it to just keep adding the data to the sheet. Like...have one variable be outputted to Columns A:B, and another variable be in C:D.